# angular 8 with ivy cannot build

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-ivy, angular-cli-v8

I migrated my package to angular 8 and i want to use ivy because i use lazy loaded modules.
When i run `ng serve` i get the following error message.

I have no idea how to track down this issue. Has anybody solved this or had a similar issue?

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.09 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 149 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.js, scripts.js.map (scripts) 40.8 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.24 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-10-23T07:19:03.231Z - Hash: 3ce8f1ee84ac94831c6b - Time: 10287ms

ERROR in The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

#### Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.13
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.13
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.13
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.13
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.13
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.13
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.13
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.13
@schematics/angular               8.3.13
@schematics/update                0.803.13
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

#### Routes:

```
export let AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'signin',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'adminbereich',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/adminsettings').then(m => m.AdminSettingsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'signin',
        component: SignInComponent,
        resolve: {
            model: SignInResolve
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'signup',
        component: SignUpComponent,
        resolve: {
            model: SignUpResolve
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'forgot-password',
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent
    }
];
```

Update: added routes

Comment: This looks like a potential issue with routing? could you share your routes?

Comment: is there a further routing file in `adminsettings` module?

Comment: yes but super basic like the AppRoutes